# How to create a function and export it into a component using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a ParentComponent and i want to use a function from another file and use it in this ParentComponent.

ParentComponent looks like below,

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const count = 5; //which is usually got by a graphql query
    const color=GetColor(count); //here it says argument of type number is 
    // not assignable to type Props.
    return (
        <ChildComponent
            color={color}/> //here the color doesnt change on variable count 
            //value change
    )
}



function GetColor({count}: Props){
    const some_color = useColor();
    const colors = [some_color.red, some_color.blue];
    return colors[count] || some_color.yellow;
}
```

I am getting error "argument of type number cannot be assigned to type Props"

Is there an easy way to write a function to just return the color taking count as argument... this function should use react-hook useColor...how can i fix this.
thanks.

Comment: Wait.. I am getting a bit confused now. Is `getColor` the same as `GetColor `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a type mismatch with the way `getColor` is declared, and the way it is used.

If `count` is a `number` is supposed to be a number, there is no need to wrap the parameters with `{..}`. If you are thinking of destructuring it, this is not the right use case to do so, as `count` is a `number`, not an object of type `Props`.

```
function getColor(count: number) {
  // do the rest
}
```

If it is supposed to be an object, you will need to convert the parameters you are supplying to the function into an object of type `Props`

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const obj: Props = {
    count: 5
  };
  const color=getColor(obj);
  // do the rest
}

function GetColor({count}: Props){
    // do the rest
}
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to call this getColor(count) directly within return statement of ParentComponent? meaning rather than assigning its return value to color variable use it directly?return ( <div color={getColor(count)}/>

Comment: also when i use function name with lowercase getColor then i am not able to use react-hook useColor within it

Comment: Ohh no, function names in react are usual lower camelcase. It is the class names that should be in upper camelcase. And no, I don't think you can directly assign it the way you mentioned.

Comment: i have used function getColor(count:number) {

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```js
const color=GetColor({count});
```

Comment: i am not sure how the function name should start..if i use const getColor then it is not allowing me to use react-hook useColor

Comment: Per convention, in javascript, you start functions with lowercase. My comment was in the sense that you created the function with uppercase but was calling it with lowercase in your question.

Comment: Ok, fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your usage it looks like `GetColor` should be either a component or another hook (that's where hooks can only be used )

You could rename `GetColor` to `useGetColor` (or something)

Then either change the signature to accept plain color value and call it like this:

```
const color = useGetColor(count)
```

Or, use destructuring like so:

```
const color = useGetColor({count})
```